# Create Drop Down Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

Hi Everyone I'm working on a website now and i want to create horizontal navigation menu with dropdown submenus. In the below i add some websites example navigation menu. When you click free tutorials you 'll get what i mean. I can create simple drop down menu with ul and li and the css's but i don't know how to assign diffirent hover color for each row.

I hope someone guide me to create this. The Link is;

http://tutsplus.com/

Thank you all

Here's the what i'm trying for

in the source code i wrote this:

```
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Main Menu</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Main Menu 2</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Sub Menu </span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item 1</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item 2</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Main Menu 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Main Menu 3</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Main Menu 4</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

and the css is

```
#menu {
  border: none;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font: 67.5% "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: auto;
}
#menu ul {
  background: #333333;
  height: 35px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
}
#menu li a {
  background: #333333 url("images/seperator.gif") bottom right no-repeat;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#menu > ul > li > a {
  color: #cccccc;
}
#menu ul ul a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#menu li > a:hover,
#menu ul li:hover > a {
  background: #58bce1 url("images/hover.png") bottom center no-repeat;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu li ul {
  background: #333333;
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 225px;
  z-index: 200;
  /*top:1em;
    /*left:0;*/

}
#menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#menu li li {
  background: url('images/sub_sep.gif') bottom left no-repeat;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 225px;
}
#menu li:hover li a {
  background: none;
}
#menu li ul a {
  display: block;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
#menu li ul a:hover,
#menu li ul li:hover > a {
  background: #58bce1 url('images/hover_sub.png') center left no-repeat;
  border: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu p {
  clear: left;
}
#menu ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}
#menu ul ul ul {
  left: -9999px;
  top: 0;
}
#menu ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 100%;
}
#menu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#menu.align-center > ul {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
#menu > ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
#menu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#menu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  text-align: right;
}
#menu.align-right ul ul li a {
  text-align: right;
}
#menu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}
```

Comment: what code have you tried to get what you want to achieve ? show that you've made some effort

Comment: Maybe post the list you have created.

Comment: I'll add mine just wait a sec

Comment: I added my work I hope you can help me now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually looking for [this](http://blog.templatemonster.com/demos/color-coded-dropdown-navigation-with-submenus/demo/index.html)

That is exactly what you want to do.

Hope will help you.

Comment: Defintely Thank so much for that

Comment: @KemalEkren You're welcome, if you want to know how it was created step by step see [this](http://blog.templatemonster.com/2014/11/10/color-coded-dropdown-navigation-with-submenus/).

Answer (score 0):

So you want to create a `hover` effect for each menu in the dropdown? So when i hover over the first one it will get red and the second will be blue?

Here's how you can do that:

```
#menu ul ul > li:nth-child(2):hover {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

Here 2 means second element. So you can add this for every element.

Here's a **[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t3d16Lxu/)** (use other selectors tho, this is just for demonstrating)

Comment: I created hover effect but also i need to make same witdh and height all of submenu's submenu and assign them diffirent color